# Get notification using NSDistributedNotificationCenter for iTunes on song info change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, itunes

I know you can use `[iTunesDNC addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateInfo:) name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];` to get a notification every time the player changes song/stops/plays/etc. But what I need is a notification every time information is changed on iTunes (ex. song title changed, lyrics changed, artist, etc)

Any suggestions? Im pretty sure I just need to change **com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo** to something else that is not *playerInfo*.

I know it should be posible, because there is an app called [SongGenie](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/songgenie/index.html) that will change its info if you edit a song's ID3 tags on iTunes or add lyrics.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Every time song info is changed iTunes posts a "**com.apple.iTunes.sourceSaved**" notification whose userInfo dictionary is the user's library.

You can check out this and other notifications that iTunes sends by listening to every notificaion posted to the Distributed Notification Center.

```
 [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(allDistributedNotifications:)
                                                  name:nil
                                                  object:nil];

- (void) allDistributedNotifications:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    NSString *object = [note object];
    NSString *name = [note name];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    NSLog(@"<%p>%s: object: %@ name: %@ userInfo: %@", self, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, object, name, userInfo);
}
```

Comment: dude, you're great thank you! haha not only saved my sanity with iTunes song change (I had almost given up) but that function to check for all notifications... hahaha I wondered if there was something like that! Thank yous!

Comment: Doesn't that give you notifications from all applications and not just iTunes?

Comment: yes it does give you all if a app send notification to NSDistributedNotificationCenter.

Comment: How did you figure out that the `com.apple.iTunes.sourceSaved` notification exists? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

or use scripting bridge, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/AboutScriptingBridge/AboutScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH3-SW9