# Cocoa : Monitor QuickTime

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quicktime

How I can "monitor" QuickTime to get some kind of notification when

- A movie is started in QuickTime (the app)
- A movie window is closed.

I know I can have the first one by watching update of the file `com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.LSSharedFileList.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences`. But it's still not very convenient.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Are you using QuickTime in your app, or do you mean the QuickTimePlayerX.app?

Comment: Yes i'm talking about QuickTimePlayerX.app.

Comment: In general you can't usually get private app info about another process since that would be a huge security hole. The [Accessibility APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html) offer some assistance with certain things, but I don't know if they allow you to detect when another app's window has been closed.

Comment: I was thinking you could use  Distributed Notification Center. as in this answer for iTunes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5846624/261305  but it looks like all of qt's Notifications are private